# Java Springboot - editing a user - mongodb without writing conditional logic

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am writing an api in Spring Boot -- and I am looking at the User model and updating process.

I am a bit unsure how to edit/save the user -- without wrapping conditions around these set/get blocks - if the age hasn't changed etc.. because the user model has a bulk of parameters -- eye color, hair color etc..

p.setAge(userDetails.getAge());

I did see this function here -- update("age", age) -- but could it just take the userDetails object and update what it has?

```
//api/users/60acbe74af509b6539701f39
@PutMapping("/api/users/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Person updateUser (
        @PathVariable(value="id", required=false) String id,
        @RequestBody Person userDetails) {

    //MongoApp.mongoOps().updateFirst(query(where("id").is("60acbbda484efb5c54add242")), update("age", age), Person.class);
    //Person p = MongoApp.mongoOps().findOne(query(where("id").is("60acbbda484efb5c54add242")), Person.class);

    Person p = MongoApp.mongoOps().findById(id, Person.class);


    p.setAge(userDetails.getAge());

    // update
    return MongoApp.mongoOps().save(p);
}
```

Comment: What is `MongoApp`? What dependency did you use for mongoDB in this spring boot application of yours?

Comment: it just returns the db ---